# HTTPListener returns the 404 error code, even though my code never tells it to

Tags: c#, .net-core

Basically, my code never sees the request, but the 404 code is returned. I can tell it's from my program, since the header of the HTTP message contains 'Server: Microsoft-NetCore/2.0'

*btw, this is my first question on Stack Overflow*

EDIT: should probably add some more info. This was working fine when I was testing the program on my machine. The HTTPListener was listening on my localhost. But when I moved it to a server, and started using a proper IP address, this issue started. The program is on an AWS EC2 instance, running Ubuntu server

Comment: 404 = not found. Maybe firewall?

Comment: Is this an MVC project? If so my suggestion would be to check the routing. There are some good debuggers out there, i tend to use https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/ - Based on the updated info in the question this unlikely the problem.

Comment: No, it's not an MVC project. Also, I dont reckon a firewall is blocking anything, since I haven't set one up

Comment: show how you have configured your listening address/port. Also, does it work if you run app locally from publish folder?

Comment: When I was testing it, I was running from source using the debugger in VSCode. On the server, I'm running it from the contents of the publish folder. On my machine, the listener runs on http://localhost:8080/. On the server, it runs on http://<local_ip>:8080/

Comment: I am having the same issue now! Do you have a solution?